# Save a word file from excel as pdf through vba

Tags: excel, vba

So I got the project working with opening the .dotx and inserting the values from the excel file and saving as .docx. 
But I can't for the life of me get it to save as .pdf instead. Well I can, but the pdf can't be opened.

```
Sub Cost_Statement()

Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document
Dim i As Integer
Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wrdApp.Visible = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

TemplateLocation = "C:\Custom documents\Cost_statement.dotx"

Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Add(TemplateLocation, False, , False)

On Error GoTo NextNumber

cellno = "Main!C19"
FindText2 = "<<EXCELCOST>>"
ReplacementText2 = Range(cellno).Value
wrdDoc.Content.Find.Execute FindText2, ReplaceWith:=ReplacementText2, Replace:=wdReplaceAll

cellno = "Main!C20"
FindText3 = "<<EXCELDEST>>"
ReplacementText3 = Range(cellno).Value
wrdDoc.Content.Find.Execute FindText3, ReplaceWith:=ReplacementText3, Replace:=wdReplaceAll

NextNumber:

FileAddress = Range("Main!C21").Text
FileAddress = "C:\Cost Statement pdfs\" & FileAddress & ".docx"

With wrdDoc

.SaveAs (FileAddress)
.Close

End With

wrdApp.Quit
Set wrdDoc = Nothing
Set wrdApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this way?

```
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:="C:\PathPDF.pdf"
```

also note that

```
FileAddress = Range("Main!C21").Text
FileAddress = "C:\Cost Statement pdfs\" & FileAddress & ".docx"
```

is the same as

```
FileAddress = "C:\Cost Statement pdfs\" & FileAddress & ".docx"
```

Comment: I think he meant also the same as: `FileAddress = "C:\Cost Statement pdfs\" & Range("Main!C21").Text & ".docx"`